# How can I programatically add a rounded border to my ImageView?

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, drawable

The way I've been able to do this so far is to create an XML drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

And in my layout XML:

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_profile_picture" />

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_default_profile_picture" />

        </FrameLayout>
```

My issue is that the frame doesn't cover the corners of the profilePicture drawable behind it, making the actual image bleed out over the border. How can I cover the corners? Really wishing there was a CSS-like property for this right about now!

Answer (score 1):

shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
```

Your layout .xml

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
    />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image"
            android:background="@drawable/shape" />

</FrameLayout>
```